# List comprehension in django orm

Tags: python, django, orm, arguments, django-orm

I have Gallery model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    TERMS_CHOICES = [
         (1, '1 month'),
         (3, '3 months'),
         (6, '6 months'),
         (12, '12 months'),
    ]
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
     editable=False)
    term = models.IntegerField(choices=TERMS_CHOICES, default=1)
```

I'm trying to create a scheduler function: it have to check expired terms, and delete the gallery. If term is null, then the term is unlimited.

How can I do it better, using django orm? Is the best way to create the list like this, or I can do it in filter? I want to use some generator comprehension like (*data, sep=' | '), but don't now how to do it correctly here:

```
 data = [
            {
                'date': '2023-02-11',
                'term': 1
            },
            {
                'date': '2022-12-11',
                'term': 3
            },
            {
                'date': '2022-09-11',
                'term': 6
            },
            {
                'date': '2022-03-11',
                'term': 12
            },
        ]

result = Gallery.objects.filter(Q(**data[0]) | Q(**data[1]) | Q(**data[2]) | Q(**data[3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that, more simple

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = date.today()
conditions = Q()
for term in TERMS_CHOICES.values:
    term_date = now - relativedelta(months=term)
    conditions |= Q(date=term_date, term=term)

result = Gallery.objects.filter(conditions)
```

But i am not sure, shouldn't we rather fit the date greater than or equal to the date calculated with the term?